# GET IP address from HttpSessionEvent

Tags: servlets, listener, ip-address, httpsession

I'm using JavaEE and have an `HttpSessionListener` implementation that I am trying to use to get an IP address when a client creates a session.  How do I do this?

My webapp is 2.4 (cannot change this, I'm afraid):

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
```

Here is my session created method:

```
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.err.println("Session source: " + se.getSource());

        System.err.println("SessionLifecycleListener:sessionCreated() not implemented yet");
        HttpSession s = se.getSession();
        printAll(s.getAttributeNames(), "HttpSession attribute names");

        ServletContext sc = s.getServletContext();
        printAll(sc.getAttributeNames(), "ServletContext attribute names");
    }
```

How do I get the IP address given the `HttpSessionEvent`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597083/how-to-get-the-ip-address-when-a-session-is-created

Comment: @Sachin: where did you read that OP is using Grails?

Comment: I'm not using Grails, but I do know how to use Google and already looked at that one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via standard Servlet API. The IP address is only available via `HttpServletRequest` and this is in turn nowhere available when having only `HttpSession` at hands.

Some if not all servlet based (MVC) frameworks offer the possibility to grab the associated HTTP request as a thread local variable (TLS), such as JSF, Grails, Spring, etc. If you aren't using such a framework and thus can't rely on its API, then you'd need to homegrow a TLS yourself as illustrated in this answer [How can I get HttpServletRequest from ServletContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492792/how-can-i-get-httpservletrequest-from-servletcontext/) Ultimately, grab it in `sessionCreated()` as below:

```
HttpServletRequest request = YourContext.getCurrentInstance().getRequest();
// ...
```

Alternatively, let the servlet filter check if the is new and then copy the IP address in there.

```
if (session.isNew()) {
    session.setAttribute("ip", ip);
}
```

Which you then extract in the `sessionCreated()`.

```
String ip = (String) event.getSession().getAttribute("ip");
```

Do note that this is not reliably possible in `sessionDestroyed()` as there's not necessarily means of a HTTP request during `sessionDestroyed()`. See also [How to get request object in sessionDestroyed method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682914/how-to-get-request-object-in-sessiondestroyed-method/)